# Как локальную переменную преобразовать в глобальную в js?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся при верстке с тем что из-за незнания базиса js простейшие функции не могу записать. Суть в том что я написал две функции, в первой считываются координаты блока в четыре переменные, две из них константы, две другие просто переменные которая регулирует высоту или ширину блока. Во второй функции переменные которые я завел как константы используются чтобы вернуть блоки в исходное положение. Вопрос в следующем: как дать доступ второй функции к константам первой? Я попробовал завести переменные перед функциями, думая, что раз у них одинаковые имена значит они прочитаются как одни и те же, но фиг там.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.blocks').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.blocks').offset(function(index, coords) {
      $(this).text('Элемент №' + index);
      const tap = coords.top;
      const laft = coords.left;
      console.log(tap, laft, index);
      var top = coords.top;
      var left = coords.left;
      if (index === 0) {
        top += 50;
      } else if (index === 1) {
        left += 50;
      } else {
        top += 50;
        left += 50;
      }
      
      return { top: top, left: left };
    });
  });

  $('.blocks').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.blocks').offset(function(index, coords) {
      $(this).text('Элемент №' + index);
      var top = 0;
      var left = 0;
      alert(tap, left, index);
      if (index === 0) {
        top = tap;
      } else if (index === 1) {
        left = laft;
      } else {
        top = tap;
        left = laft;
      }
      
      return { top: top, left: left };
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blocks" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: pink;"></div>
<div class="blocks" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: orange;"></div>
<div class="blocks" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: lime;"></div>
```

Comment: А что должен делать код? Как сработает mouseleave, если при попытке наведения, все блоки убегают?)

Comment: Ну, смысл не в том что блоки убегают, а в том что они должны возвращаться на прежнее положение. Я мог повесить на click, но это просто концепт и  создан он для проверки идеи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var tap;
  var laft;
  $('.blocks').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.blocks').offset(function(index, coords) {
      $(this).text('Элемент №' + index);
      tap = coords.top;
      laft = coords.left;
```